# How to setup Ionic Project with different ionic versions (2.2 and 3.0) in same PC?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to create 2 projects with ionic version 2.2 and 3.0 respectively.
The current ionic version installed in my PC is 3.0. Kindly tell me how to create another project with ionic version 2.2 so that both versions work together without uninstalling the previous one.

Comment: you want to create a new project with older version? or you have a project with ionic-angular 2.x? I wouldnt suggest starting a project with 2.x now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Global version of Ionic at 3.20.0, and I was able to install an Ionic 2.2.3 app. It was a little tedious though.

1. Create a new dir (we'll use **ionic2** for this purpose)
2. Within **ionic2** run `npm install ionic@legacy`   (don't use -g)
3. Change path for your current console session to include `node_modules\.bin` **FIRST** in your path

   Windows example: `set path=node_modules\.bin;%PATH%`

   `ionic -v` should give 2.2.3
4. Within **ionic2**, create your starter app: `ionic start myapp [template]`
5. cd to `myapp` and run (again) `npm install ionic@legacy`   (don't use -g), which will also add `"ionic": "^2.2.3",` to your `package.json`
6. Check your Ionic version from within myApp directory

   `ionic -v` should give 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use vmware software to run two different ionic version. One system use ionic 3 and another system use ionic 2